# Convert NPY File to a specific format in Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I have a numpy file that looks like the screenshot below. Numbers in the cells are cosine similarity between two nodes.

[Numpy File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lrZ8.png)

How can I write codes to convert them into DataFrame in this format?

[Converted DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N7Gp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a faster and more concise answer but this is the best thing that I can do.

Make a numpy array first.

```
my_array = np.array([[1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2],
                     [0.4, 1, 0.5, 0.7],
                     [0.2, 0.5, 1, 0.3],
                     [0.2, 0.7, 0.3, 1],
                     [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

And store the number of rows and columns in a variable.

```
row_num = my_array.shape[0]
col_num = my_array.shape[1]
```

Lastly, create a dataframe by placing row numbers in Node_A and column numbers in Node_B.

```
column_names = ['Node_A', 'Node_B', 'Similarity']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
for row in range(row_num):
    for col in range(col_num):
        my_dict = dict(zip(column_names, [row, col, my_array[row, col]]))
        df = df.append(my_dict, ignore_index=True)
```